# Redirection with header() won't work no matter what

Tags: php

(Have spent the entire day with this, partly because PHP, Eclipse and web programming in general are not my specialty. Maybe someone here could help).

My code in `register.php` won't redirect to `verify.php`. Here's the code:

```
header ( "Location: verify.php" );
die ( "Redirecting to activation" );
```

It simply prints `Redirecting to activation` in the browser and remains on `register.php`.

Things that I have already tried:

- I have ensured that the code actually performs everything up to just above the `header` line.
- My file doesn't have any html or white spaces before the `<?php` block.
- Adding `ob_start()` at the top doesn't appear to change anything.
- the `<?php` block doesn't have any `echo` or `print`.

### Edit

As asked, here's the entire `register.php`:

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

function isValid() {
    try {
        $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';

        $data = array (
                'secret' => 'asdf4234234kljsd32902341',
                'response' => $_POST ['g-recaptcha-response'],
                'remoteip' => $_SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR']
        );

        $options = array (
                'http' => array (
                        'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                        'method' => 'POST',
                        'content' => http_build_query ( $data )
                )
        );

        $context = stream_context_create ( $options );
        $result = file_get_contents ( $url, false, $context );
        return json_decode ( $result )->success;
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        return $e->getMessage ();
    }
}
function RunScalarQuery($db, $q, $params) {
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare ( $q );
        $result = $stmt->execute ( $params );
    } catch ( PDOException $ex ) {
        die ( "Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage () );
    }

    $row = $stmt->fetch ();
    if ($row)
        return $row [0];
        else
            return null;
}
function SendMail($smtpServer, $username, $pwd, $port, $from, $fromName, $to, $toName, $cc, $bcc, $subject, $body, $altBody) {
    require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer ();

    $mail->isSMTP (); // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = $smtpServer; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = $username; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = $pwd; // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = $port; // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom ( $from, $fromName );
    $mail->addAddress ( $to, $toName ); // Add a recipient
    if (! empty ( $cc ))
        $mail->addCC ( $cc );


        if (! empty ( $bcc ))
            $mail->addBCC ( $bcc );

            $mail->isHTML ( true ); // Set email format to HTML

            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body = $body;
            $mail->AltBody = $altBody;

            if ($mail->send ()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return $mail->ErrorInfo;
            }
}

ob_start();
if (! empty ( $_POST )) {
    // Ensure that the user fills out fields
    if (empty ( $_POST ['username'] )) {
        die ( "Please enter a username." );
    }
    if (empty ( $_POST ['inputPassword'] )) {
        die ( "Please enter a password." );
    }
    if (! filter_var ( $_POST ['inputEmail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )) {
        die ( "Invalid E-Mail Address" );
    }

    $Res = isValid ();
    if (! $Res) {
        die ( $Res );
    }

    // Check if the username is already taken
    $UsernameExists = RunScalarQuery ( $db, "SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE username = :username", array (
            ':username' => $_POST ['username']
    ) );

    if ($UsernameExists != null) {
        die ( "This username is already in use" );
    }

    $EmailExists = RunScalarQuery ( $db, "SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE email = :email", array (
            ':email' => $_POST ['email']
    ) );

    if ($EmailExists != null) {
        die ( "This email address is already registered" );
    }

    // Add row to database
    $query = "
    INSERT INTO users (username, password, salt, email, token, ActivationCode)
                VALUES (:username, :password, :salt, :email, :token, :code)";

    // Security measures
    $salt = dechex ( mt_rand ( 0, 2147483647 ) ) . dechex ( mt_rand ( 0, 2147483647 ) );
    $password = hash ( 'sha256', $_POST ['inputPassword'] . $salt );
    for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round ++) {
        $password = hash ( 'sha256', $password . $salt );
    }

    $token = dechex ( mt_rand ( 0, 2147483647 ) ) . dechex ( mt_rand ( 0, 2147483647 ) );
    $token = hash ( 'sha256', $token );
    for($round = 0; $round < 256; $round ++) {
        $token = hash ( 'sha256', $token . $salt );
    }

    // activation code
    $act_code = mt_rand ( 10000000, 99999999 );

    $query_params = array (
            ':username' => $_POST ['username'],
            ':password' => $password,
            ':salt' => $salt,
            ':email' => $_POST ['inputEmail'],
            ':token' => $token,
            ':code' => $act_code
    );

    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare ( $query );
        $result = $stmt->execute ( $query_params );
    } catch ( PDOException $ex ) {
        die ( "Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage () );
    }

    $_SESSION ['registered_email'] = $_POST ['inputEmail'];

    $mailContent = file_get_contents ( 'VerificationEmail.html' );

    $mailContent = str_replace ( "[UserName]", $_POST ['username'], $mailContent );
    $mailContent = str_replace ( "[Email]", $_POST ['inputEmail'], $mailContent );
    $mailContent = str_replace ( "[Code]", $act_code, $mailContent );
    $mailContent = str_replace ( "[EncodedEmail]", urlencode ( $_POST ['inputEmail'] ), $mailContent );

//  SendMail(...); //localhost version

    SendMail ( ...); //online version

    header ( "Location: verify.php" );
    die ( "Redirecting to activation" );
    exit();
}

$head_content = '<link href="Content/full.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="Content/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="Content/validetta.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
                <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>';
$body_class = 'class="full"';
$menu_content = '';
$body_content = 'register_body.php';
$script_content = 'register_script.php';
include ('master.php');

ob_flush();
?>
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/768472/3933332 (*Absolute URL*)

Comment: @Rizier123: using absolute URL didn't change anything.

Comment: @dotNET Does the redirect fails even when you only just have those two lines in the code?

Comment: add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);` to top of register.php

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez: Added full `register.php` code

Comment: How do you ensure that `SendMail ( ...);` is not stopping the script there or crashing? It is even reaching `SendMail ( ...);`?

Comment: Get rid of everything and just keep this one line: `header ( "Location: verify.php" );` What happens?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez: I actually receive the sent email in my Mail client.

Comment: I would save something in a file BEFORE and AFTER the "header" : `$fil = fopen("test.txt","a");
fwrite($fil, "123");
fclose($fil);
`. Save "123" before, and "456" after, for example.

Comment: Wait, replace `fopen("test.txt","w");` by `fopen("test.txt","a");` (oops!). If both lines execute, the file will contain "123456".

Comment: This probably won't fix the issue, but the `header` will redirect before it gets to `die("Redirecting to activation" );` and the `exit;` is redundant. Since you *should* never see the `die( "Redirecting to activation" );` happen, just delete it.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez From the manual: `die — Equivalent to exit`. The OP is exiting twice, but trying to write to the page with `die()`....but they are redirecting before that...logically that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Check your log for a "Headers already sent" warning.

Comment: Changed my mind, add `ob_end_clean();` just before `header`.

Comment: hmm... had to step away for a few minutes. thanks for so many suggestions. not sure what to start with, but i'll try them out and get back.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez: LOL. Not that thing. Ramadan days, so I had to take my meal to start day long fast.

Comment: @Rasclatt: As I mentioned in the post, I get `Redirecting to activation` line in the browser, so it looks like the `die` line is executing.

Comment: Yeah, that is probably messing up your redirect then. Did you remove it and see if it finishes redirecting? If you need messaging, then you may need to have it output that message with a javascript to redirect on a countdown. You can not have browser output in combination with a `header('Location:  ....etc');`

Comment: As @Barmar notes, you may be running into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php?rq=1

Comment: @Rasclatt Printing something after `header()` shouldn't mess it up, it's only messed up by printing something **before** `header()`. Since the redirect isn't working, he must be printing something before it, and the "Headers already sent" warning message will tell what line that happened on.

Comment: @Barmar That is a good point and I stopped and paused on that for a moment, but I never count anything out. It *should* never get to that point as you say and likely has output before. My first comment was that I didn't think it would solve it, but that it was not logical and could be removed (the `die()` portion).

Comment: @Rasclatt It does get to that point, but the output would be ignored by the browser because it follows the redirect in the header.

Comment: @Barmar I think you are right thought, there has to be something before.

Comment: @Everyone: Phew... figured it out. My `config.php` (first line of the code) had an extra invisible character (like I had to press DEL key twice at the beginning of the file to remove that starting `<` character) at the very start of the file. Don't know where it came from. Removing that char and saving the file got things back on track. Thanks to everyone for participation. Couldn't have discovered it without your input.

Answer (score 0):

So for any future reader, it is very important to ensure that your script really isn't spitting any content before your issue a redirect. In my case, the script had an *invisible*, zero-width character at the very start; just before the starting `<?php` tag. All my attempts to introduce fixes like `ob_start()` and removing `echo` and `print` calls failed till I realized where the problem actually was.